# can i use born and raised in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Is this line correct? 
***As i born and raised in Dhaka that's why Dhaka has always been a special land for me.*** 
Or should i say this in another way?

Comment: ***Born and raised*** is an idiomatic expression:  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/born+and+raised - ***I was born and raised*** in Dhaka (that's why Dhaka has always been a special place for me).

Comment: No, it's not correct.  The personal pronoun I is always capitalized in English.

Comment: Visit [ell.se] if you wish to learn English.

Answer (score 3):

***"I was born and brought up in Dhaka, so it has been a special land for me."***

That would be a more accurate sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I would write the sentence as, "As I was born and raised in Dhaka...". You can use them in the same sentence.